# Is there a way to find nearest adjacent line segment on both sides of a line in excel?

Tags: excel

I have roughly 1000 line segments defined by their start and end points that i have converted from lat. long. to an arbitrary x,y system in feet(i know its not exact but the scales I am dealing with make it a non issue) They all run roughly parallel and they never intersect. Also I only need to look 2000' to either side to find adjacent lines, and there will never be more than 10 that fall within that area. I do not want to look beyond the 2 end points, so if 2 segments are essentially end to end on the same plane, I do not want that line to be returned as the answer. I currently have the segments stored in several ways, the simplest being 4 columns; X0,Y0,Xf,Yf

Comment: Once you clarify what you want (it is somewhat vague) it should be doable in VBA, but probably not using just spreadsheet formulas (at leas not without heroic work). I recommend writing a program to do this, one that makes the up to 499,500 possible pairwise comparisons and bases its decision on those. I would start by writing a function which takes 4+4 = 8 numbers representing two such line segments and returns their distance (something which you would need to precisely define). Ask a question if you get stuck in your coding.

Comment: Further thought -- you did say roughly parallel, if the lines are *sorted* on e.g. a north-south axis then it might be easier than I thought. It would help if you describe the layout in more detail. One of the ways that it might be easier -- you could just take distance between midpoints of 2 parallel line as a decent measure of their distance (as long as the lines are of comparable length)